# Excel 2013 Slow to open over FTP

Tags: ftp, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a user who's opening a 2 MB file over our FTP network. It takes the system about 40 seconds to open it after the password (set through standard Microsoft file encryption no macros or add-ins enabled) is entered for the file to appear, then the system immediately goes non responsive.

All system resource values are below 50% utilized at this point, user is running Office 2013 x64 bit. Our network usually doesn't behave this way with files below 200 MB and there is less traffic on it than a typical day. Originally user got an OLE error however I changed Dynamic Data exchange to ignore and that issue went away, still slow however. This problem does not occur when the file is saved locally.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance. Still new to network troubleshooting.

Comment: FTP? Is this user on the same network or working remotely? Are you sure we’re talking about FTP? Why would you be using FTP to store office files?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I am talking about an FTP server. User is on the same network that FTP server is on. It's not that we like using FTP as a storage space, it's just the best solution we have at this point in time.